# Camera Cards and Gimp

Tags: colors, photos, gimp

I have three camera cards: white, 18% gray, and black. These are used to fix the colors of the photos that are taken. I took a picture with all three of these cards at the beginning of the shoot.

My question is: How can I get GIMP to correct the color of the photos based on these cards? Also, how can I apply the transformation to the photos after the one that contains the cards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you do this:

- Load the image with the color cards.
- Go to *Image » Color Tools » Levels*
- Use the color pickers to choose the cards
- Create a name of the color profile and save it from the *Levels* dialog
- See how badly your camera picks out colors.

When you have the other photos open, just select the saved profile from the *Levels* dialog.